# How to trigger a window on resize event from another window?

Tags: javascript

I can't find an example that actually addresses my environment.

I have a native web page (primary window) with lots of scripts I have to work with and don't want to have to forward these to the new window that I'm opening.

From the primary window, I have a js function that then opens up a new window (secondary window)

What I need to do is when creating the instance of this secondary window is to attach a listener for when the secondary window is resized, BUT use this event to trigger a js function that originates from the primary window.

```
// Function only accessible from primary window
function openNewWindow() {

    /* vendors contains the element we're looking for */
    var windowName = 'Chart' + chartId;
    var w = window.open('_blank', windowName, 'left=0,top=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=2,status=0');

    w.onresize = function (event) {

        // Do something here - in my case I need to trigger a local
        // function that is only accessible in my primary window script.
        console.log("OK"); // This does NOT Work!
    };
}
```

Comment: I would go with using `localStorage` and the `storage` event. I know this works across tabs, can't see why it wouldn't with separate windows.

Comment: Using localStorage for what? can you please elaborate further? thx

Comment: Changing anything in `localStorage` will trigger the event, OJB1. Doesn't matter a whole lot what you do with it exactly, it's just for the cross-tab communication.

Comment: OK thanks, I'm looking into this now and will test some ideas

Comment: Trying to figure out if this could be done for session storage instead, given I don't have any reason to store values in the browser beyond the current session.

Comment: I cant get the localStorage on change event to fire in the primary window, even though I have been able to validate that each time I resize the secondary window, I am in fact updating an item in local storage. Trying to follow official docs on this but no working for me for some reason.

Comment: Realised why it wasn't firing, I was updating a local storage variable with the same value each time, looks like the localStorage event will only fire IF the variable or item being updated is a completely different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having spent some time on this, I decided to update my answer as I found a more efficient solution than using localStorage which is what one of the other forum members suggested to look at, and was in fact the core of my original answer before updating it.

So, have a look at [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)

A rather cool way in creating a publish/subscribe communication channel between browser TABs & Browser Windows, which I believe is only intended to operate within the same origin/domain (but that works for me :)

OK, so in my example below, I essentially have a Web browser Window A & Window B.

Window A is my native app, I have a need to open up a new window (Window B). In my case I'm opening up this new window to display a chart. When the window B is resized by the end user, I want to trigger a JavaScript function that is stored in Window A in order that I can re-draw the chart to fit the new canvas size.

The cool thing with the Broadcast Channel API is that you can pass objects/arrays and other goodies through the channel, most of the examples found on the web are very basic and show only passing a simple string message so I thought it'd be better to show a sample using an object.

In the example below, you'll see that I instantiate the broadcast channel (bs) in the script we add to Window B only, because this same script is already present in Window A, in essence you only need to new up an instance of the bc channel once, the browser debug will warn you anyway if you try and new up the same channel more than once.

Sample code in Window A:

```
// window.open(URL, name, specs, replace)
// _blank - URL is loaded into a new window, or tab. This is default
// _parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
// _self - URL replaces the current page
// _top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
// name - The name of the window(Note: the name does not specify the title of the new window)
function openWindow(chartId, chartType) {

    var windowName = 'Chart' + chartId;
    var w = window.open('_blank', windowName, 'left=0,top=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=2,status=0');

    // We html we want to add to the new Window B
    var myHtmlCode =
        '<html>'
        + '<head>'
        //+ "<script type='text/javascript'>"
        //+ "/* this is inline script inserted by JavaScript, below is a function converted to it's string representation */"
        //+ someFuncInVariable.toString(); // Sample js function.
        //+ "</script>"
        + '<style>'
        + '.chartContainer { position: relative; height:100%; min-height:100%; width:100%; min-width: 100%; outline: none; touch-action: none; background-color: #191919; padding: 0px; }'
        + '</style>'
        + '</head>'
        + '<body>'
        // This is the js script that we open up in the new Window B
        + "<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/chart-custom-scripts/chartWindow.js'></script>"
        + '<div class="chartContainer container-fluid p-0 m-0" id="canvasContainer">'
        + '<canvas class="" tabindex="1" id="chartCanvas" aria-label="Chart Canvas" role="img"></canvas>'
        + '<div value="' + chartId + '" id="chartIdDiv"></div>'
        + '<div value="' + chartType + '" id="chartTypeDiv"></div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</body>'
        + '</html>';

    w.document.write(myHtmlCode);
    w.document.close();
}

// Note: the bc was instantiated in the chartWindow.js file which is
// also added as a script to a new window when opening up a new chart.
// see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API
bc.onmessage = (messageEvent) => {
    const data = messageEvent.data
    
    switch (data.type) {

        case 'chartResized':
            var chartId = data.object.chartId;
            var chartType = data.object.chartType;
            //console.log(data.object.chartId); // testing only...
            //console.log(data.object.chartType); // testing only...

            switch (chartType) {

                case "bar":
                    // code block
                    renderBarChartConfig(chartId, 'resize'); // Run the function below to re-draw the chart.
                    break;

                case "horizontalBar":
                    // code block
                    renderBarChartConfig(chartId, 'resize'); // Run the function below to re-draw the chart.
                    break;

                case "line":
                    // code block
                    renderBarChartConfig(chartId); // Run the function below to re-draw the chart.
                    break;

                case "pie":
                    // code block
                    renderBarChartConfig(chartId); // Run the function below to re-draw the chart.
                    break;

                case "doughnut":
                    // code block
                    renderBarChartConfig(chartId); // Run the function below to re-draw the chart.
                    break;

                case "polarArea":
                    // code block
                    renderBarChartConfig(chartId); // Run the function below to re-draw the chart.
                    break;

                case "radar":
                    // code block
                    renderBarChartConfig(chartId); // Run the function below to re-draw the chart.
                    break;
            }
            break
        default:
            console.log('we received a message')
    }
};
```

Sample Code script added to Window B:

```
// Create or join the broadcast channel.
const bc = new BroadcastChannel('charts_channel');

// Run the function when the page loads.
window.onload = function () {

    setTimeout(function () {
        // Eventlistener for when the window is resized.
        // We add a small time delay in order that we only
        // fire the reisze event once the window has resized as opposed
        // to firing multiple events throughout the course of the window
        // being resized.
        // see https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/firing-resize-event-only-once-when-resizing-is-finished/
        var resizeId;
        window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
            clearTimeout(resizeId);
            resizeId = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500); // 500 milliseconds pause before we process reseize event.
        });

    }, 2000);
}

function doneResizing() {
    //whatever we want to do
    // Run code here, resizing has "stopped"
    var chartId = this.document.getElementById("chartIdDiv").getAttribute('value');
    var chartType = this.document.getElementById("chartTypeDiv").getAttribute('value');

    var chart = {
        chartId: chartId,
        chartType: chartType
    };

    bc.postMessage({ type: 'chartResized', object: chart });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AddEventListener method isntead.

```
w.addEventListener('resize', () => console.log('OK'));
```

Comment: I tried that before but unfortunately it's still not firing anything when viewing the console for the primary page.